# Sharepoint Site with Excel Sheet Template for Users to create New Sheets

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am tasked in work with creating a share-point site. Here are my requirements:

The main page must allow the user to create a new "File".

The file must be an excel sheet template that i will style to my liking.

After the user creates a new "File", the Excel sheet is opened in the webpage for them to edit. They can save it and reopen later.

Many other users will create new "files" also - same process - same template. If i change the template then any new files use the new template.

When files are created the user must put it into a section that high level describes the location of our plant that the "file" is relevant for . e.g Some users will put files under the "Company Shipping category" category and others the "Company receiving category".

Any user can search any or all "files" for full textual searches and also within categories of our company plant (as described in item Above)

Is all this possible and what is the easiest method - Any examples of this would be great.

Comment: why is the word "File" in quotes so many times?  Is there a misunderstanding on what a file is or are there multiple assumptions?

Comment: no reason other than its an excel template that all users must start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute easiest way to do this would be to create two lists, one for Shipping and one for Receiving and define a [different Excel template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/set-a-file-template-for-a-document-or-form-library-HA010377912.aspx) for each to use whenever the user creates a new item.

If all documents must reside in the same library then you could create [custom content types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/add-multiple-office-templates-to-a-document-library-HA102409514.aspx#_Toc283114139) and then have a different template for each of the content types.

You could also look at the actual data being stored in Excel and see if it really should be in Excel or if it is merely in Excel because that is how it has always been done.  It is quite possible that a relatively simple list in SharePoint with properly defined fields could eliminate the need for Excel entirely.

Of course, since we are talking about SharePoint, there are probably half a dozen other possible solutions as well!

Comment: if i stick with excel files then is the content searchable?

Comment: As long as your search is running properly, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with seeing if it can be achieved with a SharePoint list but if it really has to be Excel then you could try using the javascript function:

```
createNewDocumentWithProgID(strTemplate, strSaveLocation, strProgID, bXMLForm)
```

This will open an Office document using the specified template and save it to the specified library.

Comment: it sounds like creating a list may be the best solution. Knowing that would you recommend any different solution?

Comment: If the template is the same then you can just use a choice column to allow users to select Shipping or Receiving.  If you need different data then you can either have 2 different content types in the same list or two separate lists.