# Hyperlink to create a new document.

Tags: document, hyperlink, template

I want to replicate the behavior of opening a office template file (e.g. .dotx).

The link should allow the user to create a new document with no attachment to a SharePoint library based on a document/template stored in a SharePoint library.

Cheers,

JJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not as easy as i first expected but here is my solution:

This block opens the new document with the designated libray as default savelocation:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="CoreInvoke('createNewDocumentWithRedirect2', event, 'http://mysite.local/project/TempLib/template.docx', 'http://mysite.local/project/Doclib', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', false, 0, true, 0);"><h2 class="ms-rteElement-H2B">New Document</h2></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Leave the savelocation empty and the user will be promptet to select a location manually i.e. the solution I was looking for initially:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="CoreInvoke('createNewDocumentWithRedirect2',event, 'http://mysite.local/project/TempLib/template.docx', '', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', false, 0, true, 0);"><h2 class="ms-rteElement-H2B">New Document</h2></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my testing I found that the first `0` argument you have should reference `_layouts/15/CreateNewDocument.aspx?id=/path/to/template.docx`, the second `0` should be `1` and a final argument `ms-word` is rquired, as per [this MSDS thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a1fe8bd8-edac-4af6-9ad0-3562688cdcc6/error-creating-new-documents-using-createnewdocumentwithprogid?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

Answer (score 0):

You can force the "download a copy" functionality by forging a link like this:

```
http://yoursite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=url-to-document
```

Comment: This approach seems to be the suggested solution when googeling but in my setup it won't fly due to access restrictions.

Comment: @Fubzot what do you mean? application pages in _layouts folder are accessible to all users. The Download a copy link you see on the ECB menu calls the download.aspx page

Comment: You are probably right, and I must admit I do not recall the specifics. Regardless I was unable to do it this way and thanks again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript function which allows this.  See answer to this question [Sharepoint Site with Excel Sheet Template for Users to create New Sheets](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68223/sharepoint-site-with-excel-sheet-template-for-users-to-create-new-sheets/68229#68229)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however i couldent get createNewDocumentWithProgID to produce the required behavior. However this lead me to stumble upon: createNewDocumentWithRedirect2 wich for my purpose does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<a onclick="CoreInvoke('createNewDocumentWithProgIDEx',event,                             
'https://Site/sites/Test/Business%20Memorandums/Forms/template.dotx', 
'https://Site/sites/Test/Business%20Memorandums', 
'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', 
false, 'ms-word')" href="#">New Document</a>
```